# How to convert Kinect.Toolbox.ReplayColorImageFrame to Kinect.ColorImageFrame

Tags: casting, type-conversion, kinect, kinect.toolbox

I do some little modifications on KinectColorViewer of the KinectSamples provided with Kinect SDK. On the KinectColorViewer i create a method that simply render a ColorImageFrame on the Image element of the viewer, my method is something like this

```
    public void UpdateColorImage(ColorImageFrame imageFrame)
    {
        RenderImageOnViewer(imageFrame); // the code of RenderImageOnViewer is omited for simplicity
    }
```

My problem is that iam using the KinectColorViewer from Kinect.Samples that receives a ColorImageFrame as parameters, and using the Recorder from Kinect.Toolbox project, that provides me a ReplayColorImageFrame.

i am tryin to convert the ReplayColorImageFrame into ColorImageFrame but ReplayColorImageFrame doesn inherit the ColorImageFrame.

How to do this?